# Cut the middle of the sentence with 3 point (PHP)

Tags: php

If the sentence is longer than 50 characters, 3 dots can be added to the last part of the sentence, but without deleting the first and last part of the sentence; Can only 3 points be added in the middle part?

For example;

> This is a new world system

To

> This ... tem

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: You can use a regular expression with capture groups for the first and last word. Or you can use `explode()` to split the sentence into words, get the first and last elements of the array, the concatenate them with `...` between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to check the length of your `string` after that if it more than
`50` characters split into words using `explode` at last print the first and last word and add `...` between them

You could try something like this one

```php
    $str = 'This is the new world system  is the new world system';
    $res = $str;

    if(strlen($str) > 50){
        $words = explode(' ', $str);
        $res = $words[0] . '...' . $words[count($words) - 1];      
    }

    echo $res;
```

you could read more about `explode` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Thank you so much @Joseph; possible with one string? for example: `$str = "2010+2011+2012+2013+2014+2015+2016+2017+2018+2019+2020)"`

Comment: all you will need to change is update `explode` and change the first param to `'+'` instead of `' '`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: you are welcome :)